# Drag and drop event in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, event-handling

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('dragDrop',  function() {
        return {

           link:function(scope,element){

              element.on('dragover', function(event) { 
                    event.preventDefault();
              });
              element.on('drop', function(event) { 
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var data=event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text");                          
         event.target.parentNode.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
              });
              element.on('drag', function(event) { 
                  event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text",event.target.id);
                  console.log(event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
                  scope.$apply();
              });
           }

        };
    });
```

The above code works very well when I adjust it as not using AngularJS. When I create the above directive for some totally unexplained reason 
`console.log(event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));` **outputs nothing**. ***Why that***? 
I also present the HTML code (drag and drop functionality between two lists):

```
<div class="col-xs-6" drag-drop>
                                            <div class="header">Available Life Events</div>
                                            <ul class="permission-levels">
                                                <li style="margin:20px;" ng-attr-id="{{'ALE'+$index}}" draggable="true"                  
                                                ng-repeat="event in Events track by $index">
                                                    {{event.name}}
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>


<div class="col-xs-6" drag-drop>
                                            <div class="header">Life Events Applied</div>
                                            <ul class="permission-levels">
                                                <li style="margin:20px;" ng-attr-id="{{'LEA'+$index}}" draggable="true"  
                                                ng-repeat="event in events track by $index">
                                                    {{event.name}}
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: In the meantime I read somewhere that data is only available on drop. However, not even inside drop event is available...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `drag` event use `dragstart`. Please check
https://plnkr.co/edit/BjnawQsQeeguC5njmQdz?p=preview

Comment: You are a star!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/angular-dragdrop/angular-dragdrop), there's [an opened issue (titled "event.dataTransfer is undefined")](https://github.com/angular-dragdrop/angular-dragdrop/issues/22) with this exact problem. Haven't tried it myself, but apparently it's not fixed properly.

Comment: I am not using that!